# Is there a way to get trending topic number of mentions from tweets in R?

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, trending

I have just started with text mining and I am trying to get through Twitter Api the tweets that are Trending topic in Liverpool now, and represent them in a wordcloud.

But when getting trendings with `getTrends` function from `twitteR` library, I am unable to find anything that corresponds to the number of mentions that trending topic has. I want this number because I want to order the trendings by their number of mentions in order to represent them correctly on the wordcloud.

The code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(wordcloud)

Locs=availableTrendLocations()
locsEngland=subset(Locs,country="United Kingdom")
id=subset(locsEngland,name=="Liverpool")
trends=getTrends(woeid = id)
trends=Corpus(VectorSource(trends$name))
trends=TermDocumentMatrix(trends)
ap.tdm=as.matrix(trends)
ap.v=sort(rowSums(ap.tdm),decreasing = T)
ap.d=data.frame(word=names(ap.v),freq=ap.v)

wordcloud(ap.d$word,ap.d$freq, scale=c(3,0.5), max.words=50, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.15, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(,"Dark2"))
```

Maybe a possible way to do this is, one trending topics are obtained, if they are ordered, enumerate them (appending a column) and use that as the terms frecuency, but guess there must be a better way although I found nothing in [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place)